# Save and restore arrangement of apps

Tags: iphone, ios, applications

I would like to experiment with the arrangement of my apps on my iPod touch. Using folders more extensively. However at the moment I have a quite well working layout. If the experiments proof to be worse than my current layout I would like to go back there easily.

*Can I somehow save the current layout of my home screens?*

Regards
Mike

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can try to backup your iPhone in iTunes, and if things aren't working, go back to that backup.

[**This article**](http://support.apple.com/kb/HT1414) on the Apple support site sums it up.

And this image explains it quite clearly.

[image: https://i.stack.imgur.com/dzGIw.png]

Comment: That doesn't always work. Sometimes it kept my apps in the folders, sometimes not, and apps not in folders are on the correct pages but the order is incorrect. At that point, I decided not to sweat the layout of my apps so much.

Answer (score 2):

The only thing that comes to mind mind are screen shots.